# Explain the order of evaluation in printf

Tags: c, printf

```
main()
{
    int i=5;
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d%d",i++,i--,++i,--i,i);
}
```

Output is 45545, but I don't how it is working. Some say that the arguments in a function call are pushed into the stack from left to right.

Comment: Careful, you have 6 format specificers `%d` and only 5 arguments...

Comment: Be very careful with a notion that arguments are passed via a *stack*. Modern compilers are trying to pass as many arguments via registers as possible.

Comment: because evaluation begins from right to left

Comment: Yes in g++, not in Visual Studio. In VS, the ++s and --s don't take effect until after the printf finishes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order in which the parameters to a function are passed is not defined in the standard, and is determined by the [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) used by the compiler.
I think in your case, [**cdecl**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) calling convention (which many C compilers use for x86 architecture) is used in which arguments in a function get evaluated from right to left.

Comment: This should also mention that the code has *undefined behaviour*.   Someone who quickly scans this Q/A without revising the other answers might overlook that fact and assume the behaviour in the question is reliable for cdecl calls.

Comment: The question is about *order of evaluation* (which is **unspecified**), not about how parameters are passed (after their evaluation).

Answer (score 21):

The evaluation order of function parameters is unspecified.

From c99 standard:

> **6.5.2.2 Function calls**
>
> 10/ The order of evaluation of the function designator, the actual
>   arguments, and subexpressions within the actual arguments is
>   unspecified, but there is a sequence point  before the actual call.

This is, however, only a part of the problem. Another thing (which is actually worse, since it involves undefined behavior) is:

> **6.5 Expressions**
>
> 2/ Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have
>   its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an
>   expression. Furthermore, the prior value  shall be read only to
>   determine the value to be stored.

In our case all the arguments evaluation is between only 2 sequence points: the previous `;` and the point before the function is entered but after all the arguments have been evaluated. You'd better not write a code like this.

C standard is pretty relaxed in some places to leave room for optimizations that compilers might do.

Comment: You should probably add a reason as to WHY it was left undefined (optimization)

Answer (score 3):

Two points:

- Function arguments are evaluated in an unspecified order. This allows the compiler to optimize however it likes.
- Your particular arguments invoke undefined behavior. You're not allowed to modify `i` multiple times before a sequence point.

Comment: *You're not allowed to modify i multiple times in a single statement.*  This is not true: for example: `i++, i++;` is a single statement and you are modifying an object twice but it is not UB.

Comment: What is the better term for this? I don't think expression fits either. I've switched to sequence point, but I don't really like the wording now.

Comment: *sequence point* is the right wording.

Answer (score 3):

This function call is undefined behavior:

```
printf("%d%d%d%d%d%d",i++,i--,++i,--i,i);
```

Modifying an object more than once between two sequence points is undefined behavior in C.

It is also undefined behavior because you have 6 conversion specifications but only 5 arguments for the format.

Comment: As comment length is limited i have rephrased the statement as printf("%d %d %d %d",i,++i, i++,i); with i=1 During evaluation, first it will take all the values starting from right into the stack. If the variable has any post/pre increment, it evaluates and stores the value. Else, it stores as a variable in the stack and takes the final value of the var. right most i - i in to the stack, for i++ - 1 because its post inc updates i as 2. for ++i - 3, pre inc and updates i as 3 for i as it is in the stack. for var as i in stack takes final value of i as 3. Final output will be 3 3 1 3

Comment: @Dinesh Thanks for the downvote but as others already told you, you are wrong. There is no "stack" in C Standard but there is a concept of *sequence points* with related requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The evaluation order of `printf` arguments is unspecified. It depends, among other, on the calling convention of the system you are using. Moreover, this is also an undefined behavior, because you are modifying `i` several times without any sequence point. BTW, there is a missing argument.

Comment: calling order is not unpsecified. it follows the order of stack by pushing elements starting from right side.

Comment: @Dinesh: You're wrong, according to C standard.