# Array of Integers Changes Content When Passed to a Function

Tags: c, arrays, function, memory

**Some Context**:
I am solving a problem from HackerRank regarding the  contiguous subsequence and subset with largest sum on a series of integers. The algorithm may be correct or not, I'm not concerened about its correctness but rather the unusual behavior of my program, please continue reading.

**input.txt**:

```
1
6
2 -1 2 3 4 -5
```

**Input Format**:

```
number of testcases
number of integers (let that be n)
n space-sepearated integers
```

**Correct Output (based on source)**:

```
10 11
```

**Actual Output**:

```
11 11
```

As you can see, the actual output does not match the correct output. I spent time manually performing the algorithm on the input using pen and paper before and after writing the program, and my computation seems to match the correct output (My algorithm may still not be correct). But afterwards, I attempted to use gdb to trace the program line by line and I found something unusual at the start of a function call to bestSum1.

**GDB Output Snippet**: (Go to the part near the end where I print integers[0] and show that the value changed when I passed it to a function.

```
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4005fe: file maxsub.c, line 14.
(gdb) break bestSum1
Breakpoint 2 at 0x400745: file maxsub.c, line 33.
(gdb) run < input.txt
Starting program: /home/ken/Desktop/dynamic prog/maxsub < input.txt
Breakpoint 1, main () at maxsub.c:14
14      scanf("%d", &T);
(gdb) n
16      for (i = 0; i < T; i++) {                   // Each testcase
(gdb) n
17          scanf("%d", &N);                    // Get size of array
(gdb) n
18          int integers[N];                    // Allocate memory
(gdb) n
20          for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {               // Fill up array
(gdb) n
21              scanf("%d", &integers[j]);
(gdb) n
< SNIPPED PART > this is basically where for loop repeats N times
(gdb) n
20          for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {               // Fill up array
(gdb) n
24          printf("%d %d\n", bestSum1(N, integers), bestSum2(N,     integers));    // Print Answer
/** START TAKING A LOOK HERE, this is where the unusual thing happens: **/
(gdb) print integers[0]     <---- INITIAL VALUE
$1 = 2                     
(gdb) print integers        <---- ADDRESS OF ARRAY
$2 = 0x7fffffffdea0   
(gdb) n

Breakpoint 2, bestSum1 (size=6, integers=0x7fffffffdea0) at maxsub.c:33
33          best_sum = - INFINITY,                  // Best Sum Found
(gdb) print integers[0]     <---- VALUE CHANGED
$3 = -5
(gdb) print integers        <---- SAME ADDRESS
$4 = (int *) 0x7fffffffdea0
(gdb)
```

**Full Source Code** :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#define INFINITY INT_MAX

int bestSum1(int size, int integers[size]);
int bestSum2(int size, int integers[size]);
int compare(const void* p1, const void* p2);

int main() {
    int T, N,   // testcases (T) and array size (N)
        i, j;   // Declare loop counters

    scanf("%d", &T);

    for (i = 0; i < T; i++) {               // Each testcase
        scanf("%d", &N);                    // Get size of array
        int integers[N];                    // Allocate memory

        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {           // Fill up array
            scanf("%d", &integers[j]);
        }

        // bestSum1 gets strictly contiguous subsequence with largest sum
        // bestSum2 gets subset of numbers with largest sum
        printf("%d %d\n", bestSum1(N, integers), bestSum2(N, integers));    
    }

    return 0;
}

int bestSum1(int size, int integers[size]) {
    // CONTIGUOUS SUBSEQUENCE WITH LARGEST SUM
    int curr_sum = 0,                   // Current Sum
        best_sum = - INFINITY,          // Best Sum Found
        value,                          // Where we store value
        i;                              // Loop Counter

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            value = curr_sum + integers[i];
        if (value <= 0) {
            curr_sum = 0;
        } else if (value > best_sum) {
            best_sum = value;
            curr_sum = best_sum;
        }
    }

    return best_sum;
}

int bestSum2(int size, int integers[size]) {
    // NON-CONTIGUOUS SUBSEQUENCE WITH LARGEST SUM
    qsort(integers, size, sizeof(int), compare);

    int sum = -1,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (integers[i] > 0) {
            sum += integers[i];
        }
    }

    return sum == -1 ? integers[size - 1] : sum;
}

int compare(const void* p1, const void* p2) {
    return *((int*) p1) - *((int*) p2);
}
```

So I want to know how to fix this and why this happens.

Comment: Isn't this just because you call `qsort` to sort the array (in place) in bestSum2? Make sure you pay attention to the order the parameters are evaluated in printf (this is not defined in the standard)!

Comment: So, you have 1 test case, and "6" integers: `2 -1 2 3 4 -5`.  What is the significance of the expected results: `10 11`?  (No matter how I sum the digits, they do not add up to 10 or 11, they sum to 5).  Why is 10 11 the correct response?

Comment: I don't think so, because bestsum2 is called after bestsum1.

Comment: `bestsum1` and `bestsum2` could be called in any order. It's not defined which gets called first.

Comment: @rykker Because the contiguous subsequence with largest sum is the sequence 2, -1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Any source/reference material with more technical explanation for that information?

Comment: @Mercado There is some good information in the answers on [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960241/explain-the-order-of-evalution-in-printf).

Comment: @Mercado: Is the [C standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) sufficient?